# How to implement a pipe using shared memory and semaphores?

Tags: c, linux, pipe, shared-memory

My current assignment is regarding implementing the `pipe()` in `Linux` using **shared memory**.

Since this is my first time working with semaphores & shared memory (`mutex` also) I have zero experience with it .

Can somebody shed some light on it with explanation regarding its implementation ? thanks

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a tutorial website. Do you understand the ingredient concepts? Do you know what shared memory is, and how to synchronise concurrent access to memory? For each of those topics you can find ample material all over the place, books, internet, or even Wikipedia. Please put some background research in and only post a question once you hit a concrete stumbling point. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with the man pages below:

**Shared memory**

```
ftok
shmget
shmat
shmctl
shmdt
```

**Semaphores**

```
sem_init
sem_wait
sem_post
```

The idea is, two different applications that will use your pipe to be able to exchange data. This can be done with shared memory. Also some synchronization should be done (here comes the semaphore) in order to be sure that the data that a process reads are consistent. For example, you have to block process A writing to the pipe until process B reads the data from the pipe from a previous write.